# Access nested XML node content in TFHppleElement

Tags: ios, objective-c, libxml2

[image: image of array]

I am trying to access the key value for "nodeContent" in the pictured array, I have no issue getting in to the right element, but I can't get in to the 'node' NSDictionary.

I have tried:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[[tutorialsNodes objectAtIndex:2]     
    objectForKey:@"nodeAttributeArray"] 
        objectAtIndex:1] 
            objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]);
```

but that only prints (null)

Comment: Split your line up into several and look at the value at each step. Your current code is impossible to debug.

Comment: Ok, I split it into the four levels I currently have. Do I need to add one to access the first drop down titled "node"?

Comment: That's not what I meant. Split each part into a separate statement and assign each result to a proper variable.